# How to write markdown config codes by lua in neovim?

Tags: markdown, neovim

I wrote config codes in `markdown.lua` file, as follows:

```lua
require('markdown-preview').setup {
  vim.g.mkdp_browser = "C:/Program\ Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
}
```

**But it doesn't work, error as follows:**

```
Error while calling lua chunk: ... /markdown.lua:2: '}' expected (to close '{' at line 1) near '='
```

I don't understand.

Comment: anyone encountered this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using [this](https://github.com/iamcco/markdown-preview.nvim) plugin, you probably need to do something like this instead:

```
vim.g.mkdp_browser = "C:/Program\ Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
require('markdown-preview').setup({})
```

`vim.g` are globals, so you usually need to set them outside of the plugin setup, before calling its `setup` function.